# nvencinitializeencoder failed when bitrate is too large

Tags: ffmpeg, nvidia, h.264

when I use ffmpeg to push  stream:

```
ffmpeg -loglevel debug  -re -i a.flv -c:v h264_nvenc -b:v 145M -maxrate:v 200M -c:a copy -f flv rtmp://localhost/live/test
```

get failure:

```
[format @ 0000000002861760] Setting 'pix_fmts' to value 'yuv420p|nv12|yuv444p'
[AVFilterGraph @ 00000000028470c0] query_formats: 4 queried, 3 merged, 0 already done, 0 delayed
[h264 @ 000000000324d2a0] nal_unit_type: 7, nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 000000000324d2a0] nal_unit_type: 8, nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264_nvenc @ 00000000028446c0] Nvenc initialized successfully
[h264_nvenc @ 00000000028446c0] 1 CUDA capable devices found
[h264_nvenc @ 00000000028446c0] [ GPU #0 - < GeForce GTX 1080 Ti > has Compute SM 6.1 ]
[h264_nvenc @ 00000000028446c0] supports NVENC
[h264_nvenc @ 00000000028446c0] InitializeEncoder failed: invalid param (8)
[h264_nvenc @ 00000000028446c0] Nvenc unloaded
Output #0, flv, to 'rtmp://localhost/live/test':
  Metadata:
    Server          : NGINX RTMP (github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module)
    displayWidth    : 1920
    displayHeight   : 960
    fps             : 0
    profile         :
    level           :
    encoder         : Lavf57.41.100
    Stream #0:0, 0, 0/0: Unknown: none, SAR 1:1 DAR 0:0
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.50.100 h264_nvenc
    Stream #0:1, 0, 0/0: Unknown: none
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (h264_nvenc))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
[AVIOContext @ 000000000322b620] Statistics: 0 seeks, 0 writeouts
```

but is success when set biterate 144M

```
ffmpeg -loglevel debug  -re -i a.flv -c:v h264_nvenc -b:v 144M -maxrate:v 200M -c:a copy -f flv rtmp://localhost/live/test
```

anybody know the limits for nvEncInitializeEncoder?

Comment: nvenc is completely orthogonal to CUDA (it has nothing whatever to do with CUDA). I have removed the tag accordingly

Comment: This is a known issue, and not directly related to ffmpeg but the Nvidia encoder. See http://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/6477